# How to use starling with Flex, mixed MXML and Stage 3D AS3 code

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, starling-framework

I need to build a mobile application using starling by creating a FlexMobileApplication project and not an ActionScriptMobileApplication project.

Can i have both MXML controls and Stage 3D (strarling content) at the same time in my app.

Comment: First: Why flex? Why you need it? Second: What you what to know asking 'did starling supported with flex and MXML'? What type of support you need?

Comment: Flex has a rich set of UI components, that's why I thought to use it, but can I still employ starling to accelerate Flex based UI component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes** you can mix them, but take note of the following:

- Starling is a framework for stage3D which runs on a lower layer than the normal Flex (non stage3D) content.
- You need to set your Application backgroundAlpha to 0 in order to be able to see the starling content.
- You will only be able to display Flex controls over Starling (and not mix them or have the reverse layering)
- there may be other points to disuss, as performance and so on but since you picked already Starling you should know the basics by now.

**Update**

If you need flex like controls on the Stage3D leyer, use Feathers Framework for Starling.

- Here are some samples: http://feathersui.com/examples/components-explorer/
- Here is the framework wiki: http://wiki.starling-framework.org/feathers/start

Comment: Sorry for my humble English! I will double check my questions later on .. so, is it possible to use Flex based UI components in the Stage3D layer? or it would have be written from scratch to extend starling.display.Sprite?

Comment: @SameerH.Ibra you cannot use flex controls inside stage3D (starling layer)  but you can use them on the normal flash layer (which runs on top of stage3D). If you want to use buttons or lists inside starling please take a look at the Feathers Framework. It contains controls like combobox, button, list, etc that are rendered on the stage3D layer.